# Running a C++ script inside a Matlab loop

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I have a C++ function that given 3 integers and a string, makes some statical tests from a matrix read from a txt file and creates as output a txt file called as the input string.

I would like to place this program in a matlab scrips that loops inside a cell array A made of sparse matrices in the following way:

```
formatSpec = string('Validated_edge_layer%d_time%d');
for k=1:size(A,1)
   for j=1:size(A,2)
      n1=size(A{k,j},1);
      n2=size(A{k,j},2);
      e=nnz(A{k,j});
      write_to_txt(A{k,j};
      string=sprintf(formatSpec,k,j);
      *** HERE I WOULD LIKE TO CALL THE C++ FUNCTION WITH INPUTS n1,n2,string ***
   end
end
```

So basically inside the loop matlab evaluates the inputs of the C++ function and writes within each iteration a txt files that is then read by the C++ function (the files gets overwritten so that the C++ function can read a new set of variables). At the end of the loop I would like to have something like 120 txt files each named differently and in an order that follows the cell array organization.

Is this task possible? I know that something called MEX files can be used but I know nothing about it.

I hope that I have explained myself clearly. Thanks.

Comment: Start by writing a simple [MEX file](http://www.shawnlankton.com/2008/03/getting-started-with-mex-a-short-tutorial/) first.

Comment: If the c++ code is compiled you can execute it with `!`.  For example `!MyCoolCProgram input1 input2 input3`.

Comment: You can compile your C++ code into `DLL` and [run DLL from Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/loadlibrary.html). When `MEX` and `EXE` are not appropriate (assuming you are using Windows).